# Call ActionResult method from button press

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to call an ActionResult method from a web page form but I can't seem get the two items to connect.

The desired result is for the page to refresh and filter the model to display the required results.

**Method in serversController.cs**

The internal code works as intended when placed in `ActionResult Index`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult activeServers()
{
    // load the servers into local variable
    var servers = from s in db.Servers
                  select s;

    // filter out the archived servers
    servers = servers.Where(s => s.archive.Equals(0));

    return View(servers.ToList());
}
```

**Button making the call**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    <button name="activeServers" type="submit" value="activeServers" class="btn btn-default">Active</button>
}
```

Thanks is advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify the action method, controller name (*without the `controller` suffix*) and the http method (it defaults to GET) in the `BeginForm`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("activeServers", "Servers", FormMethod.POST))
{ 
    <button name="activeServers" type="submit" value="activeServers" class="btn btn-default">Active</button>
}
```

Comment: Using that code I get sent to the url `http://localhost:23952/serversController/activeServers` along with a 404 error. The url should be `http://localhost:23952/servers/Index`. Replacing the controller name with servers reaches the method but the the web page displays an error, stating its looking for a view called `activeServers`.

Comment: You action is called `activeServers` if you want to send requests to it, then you should specify it in the BeginForm. I'll update the part regarding controller name